# Access Query, if text in column then write the data

Tags: sql, ms-access

Because this thing is due tomorrow I really need the help of our lovely community, right now I just started learning MS Access and SQL but encountered some difficulties.

What I want to do is a simple query, we can call it as a activity query, which will show us the activity of a member of the group in projects (proiect).

Here I have the table with the projects in which each member of a group participated.

[image]

[image]

- `ID-p-m` is the ID of the project manager in the database
- `ID-p-t` is the ID of each team member in the database ( Bart - 5 ; Donny - 8 ; Mike - 9)

The query I am trying to make has as the user input the ID of the member.

Let's say ( 12 )

What I would like to get is something looking like this :

[image]

The raw code is kinda like this

```
Get ID ( in our case 12 ). 
Analyze column ID-p-m; 
if ID-p-m LIKE Get-ID:
get- Nume Proiect , 
print in Took part : [Nume Proiect] + " -  Project Manager "  
Analyze column ID-p-t;
if ID-p-t LIKE Get-ID:
get- Nume Proiect ,
print in Took part : [Nume Proiect] + " - Project Team "
```

I can resolve the name part by myself, the hard thing for me is the " Took part:" thing... I really look forward to learning access and sql, but right now I need your help because this is due tomorrow.

Some literature on on how to do this, would also be awesome.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Presumably the database is MS Access as mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure violates the [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and this makes your query really difficult.

You should have:

### Projects

```
ProjectID
ProjectName
```

### People

```
PeopleID
PeopleName
```

### Roles

This is a junction table to create the many-to-many relationship between Projects and People!

```
ProjectID
PeopleID
Role  (e.g. "Project Member" or "Project Manager")
```

With the right table structure, your query will follow almost by itself.